# Drupal submit contact form from api

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

Help, please, there is a task from the front on api to fill out the drupal contact form.

I have a contact form and a method, I need help with the code that will submit the data, I found this solution:

```
$form_state = new FormState();
$values = [
            'message' => 'test',
            'name'  => 'test'
          ];
$form_state->setValues($values);
\Drupal::formBuilder()->submitForm('data_portal_contact_us', $form_state);
```

In the log it gives the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The form argument data_portal_contact_us is not a valid form. in Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->getFormId() (line 197 of /www/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use The Form class Name in the **$form_arg** parameter of **submitForm($form_arg, FormStateInterface &$form_state)**

```
$values = [
            'message' => 'test',
            'name'  => 'test'
          ];
$form_state = (new FormState())->setValues($values);
\Drupal::formBuilder()->submitForm('Drupal\module_name\Form\customModuleNameForm', $form_state);
```